# QB64 unable to load image, saying "illegal function call"

Tags: image, qb64

im trying to load an image for my game title instead of ASCII, but when i try to load the image, it says that `_PUTIMAGE, i&. 0` is an illegal function call.
Does `_PUTIMAGE,i&` not work for certain file types?

I've tried all the ways the built-in help suggest i load an image, but none of them work.

```
menu:
CLS
PRINT
i& = _LOADIMAGE("FOrest.jpg")
_PUTIMAGE, i&
PRINT ""
PRINT "What Will Your Heros Name be?:";
Name$ = Ask$(5, 1, CSRLIN, POS(0), 11, 0)
CLS
check_1% = 0 'placeholder for debugingg
COLOR 15, 0
PRINT Name$ + "How Old will Your Hero be?: ";: age% = VAL(Ask$(3, 0, CSRLIN, POS(0), 15, 0))
'INPUT "", age%
```

i want this image to be loaded [image: Game title image]

Answer (score 2):

> The *sourceHandle&* and *destHandle&* cannot be the same or an **Illegal Function Call** error will occur

Try specifying an explicit destination handle. You want the screen so select 0.

- method 1

  ```
  i& = _LOADIMAGE("forest.jpg")
  _PUTIMAGE , i&, 0
  ```
- method 2

  ```
  i& = _LOADIMAGE("forest.jpg")
  _SOURCE i&
  _DEST 0
  _PUTIMAGE
  ```

---

It would be best if you verified if loading the image was successful. Check if `i&` is less than -1.

---

Did you at least setup a graphics screen for your .jpg picture?

```
SCREEN 13
i& = _LOADIMAGE("forest.jpg")
_PUTIMAGE , i&, 0
```

Comment: @Sep_Ronland i havent verified its loading but i will do that and eply, thank you for the help i will see if this will work for me

Comment: how would i check that `i&` is -1?

Comment: Returns -1 as an invalid handle if it could not load the image. Valid LONG handle returns are less than -1.

Comment: the check for seeing if `i&` is -1 doesn't work for some reason says `illegal function call`

Answer (score 1):

Are you in SCREEN 0 or in a graphics mode?

Comment: im using `SCREEN 12`

Answer (score 1):

doing

```
SCREEN _NEWIMAGE(640, 480, 32) 
i = _LOADIMAGE("FOrest.jpg.png") 'this filename was the only one that worked
_PUTIMAGE (0, 0), i
```

worked but I cant do my other inputs i have at that point where the image loads.
this was in the built in help but previously didnt work. so this is weird, i guess when it works it works

Comment: due to it not being in `screen 12` anymore

Answer (score 0):

Check if image was loaded correctly:

```
SCREEN _NEWIMAGE(640, 480, 32)
CLS , _RGB(0, 255, 0)
i& = _LOADIMAGE("FOREST.JPG")
IF i& = -1 THEN PRINT "invalid image": END
_PUTIMAGE (0, 0), i&, 0
END
```